# React Router Inserting Content into the BaseLayout

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a single page React app. I have a BaseLayout component which serves as the container for the app. BaseLayout displays the header and footer and also the content as shown below:

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (

      <div>
        <BaseLayout>

        </BaseLayout>
      </div>

    );
  }
}
```

**BaseLayout**

```
export default class BaseLayout extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
      <NavBar />
      {this.props.children}
      <Footer />
      </div>
    )
  }

}
```

**index.js**

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/page_one" component={PageOne} />
      <Route path="/page_two" component={PageTwo} />
      <Route path="/" component={App} />
    </Switch>
  </BrowserRouter>,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

All the navigation is inside the navBar.js component.

**navBar.js**

```
export default class NavBar extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="nav-bar">
      <button><Link to="/">Home</Link></button>
      <button><Link to="/page_one">Page One</Link></button>
      <button><Link to="/page_two">Page Two</Link></button>
    </div>
    )
  }

}
```

**pageOne.js and pageTwo.js**

```
export default class PageOne extends Component {

   constructor(props) {
     super(props)
   }

   render() {
     return (

       <div>
       <h1>Page One </h1>
       </div>


     );
   }

}
```

The problem is that when I go to page_one or page_two URL it only shows the content of the component and not the navigation bar.

How can I make the navigation bar and footer visible on all the pages using react router and react framework?

UPDATE:

**App.js**

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (

      <div>
        <BaseLayout>

        </BaseLayout>
      </div>

    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

**I changed my index.js to the following:**

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <BrowserRouter>
        <Route path="/" component={App}>
            <Switch>
                <Route path="/page_one" component={PageOne} />
                <Route path="/page_two" component={PageTwo} />
            </Switch>
        </Route>
    </BrowserRouter>,
    document.getElementById('root')
)
```

Now, I get the following:

[image]

And the page does not go anywhere if I use the above code:

Answer (score 0):

I think you should "lift" the `App` as the root `Route`.
By the way, Is `App` the same as `BaseLayout`? hard to tell from your example.
Example:

```
const Index = () => {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <div>
        <Route component={App} />
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/page_one" component={PageOne} />
          <Route path="/page_two" component={PageTwo} />
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
};
```

[A running code example](https://codesandbox.io/s/q7zrln25o9), i'm not using a stack snippet as i can't use react-route with push state here.

I'm posting the entire code in case the url will be broken in the future:

```
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Link, Switch } from "react-router-dom";

const Footer = () => <div>Footer...</div>;

class BaseLayout extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <NavBar />
        {this.props.children}
        <hr/>
        <Footer />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class NavBar extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="nav-bar">
        <button>
          <Link to="/">Home</Link>
        </button>
        <button>
          <Link to="/page_one">Page One</Link>
        </button>
        <button>
          <Link to="/page_two">Page Two</Link>
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const PageOne = () => <h1>Page One</h1>;
const PageTwo = () => <h1>Page Two</h1>;

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <BaseLayout>{this.props.children}</BaseLayout>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const Index = () => {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <div>
        <Route component={App} />
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/page_one" component={PageOne} />
          <Route path="/page_two" component={PageTwo} />
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
};

render(<Index />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Comment: Updated the code with App.js implementation. App is not the same as BaseLayout.

Comment: add `{this.props.children}` inside the `render` of `App` as well then

Comment: I added it but it did not do anything. The problem I am facing is that when I go to page_one I don't see the navigation menu.

Comment: @johndoe i had a typo in the routes, I've updated my question and have included a running example.